Btrfs snapshots are empty
I am using btrbk to make snapshots of my @home subvolume, but the snapshots are empty, zero bytes.
I think I need to automount home, somehow.
I see in the Btrfs Assistant File Viewer that the root subvolume called "@" has both "@home" and "home" listed under it, and "@home" is unpopulated.
 sudo btrbk run
[sudo] password for shmuel: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Backup Summary (btrbk command line client, version 0.32.6)

    Date:   Mon Apr 29 20:43:36 2024
    Config: /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf

Legend:
    ===  up-to-date subvolume (source snapshot)
    +++  created subvolume (source snapshot)
    ---  deleted subvolume
    ***  received subvolume (non-incremental)
    >>>  received subvolume (incremental)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/@home
+++ /.snapshots/@home.20240429T2043

but it comes out empty.
My subvolumes look like this:
    sudo btrfs subvolume list -p /
ID 256 gen 2674 parent 5 top level 5 path @
ID 257 gen 2667 parent 5 top level 5 path @home
ID 258 gen 2667 parent 256 top level 256 path srv
ID 259 gen 68 parent 256 top level 256 path var/lib/portables
ID 260 gen 68 parent 256 top level 256 path var/lib/machines
ID 261 gen 2674 parent 256 top level 256 path tmp
ID 262 gen 2657 parent 256 top level 256 path var/tmp
ID 263 gen 2645 parent 256 top level 256 path .snapshots/@home.20240429T2031
ID 264 gen 2665 parent 256 top level 256 path .snapshots/@home.20240429T2043

The system is NixOS
The btrbk config file looks like this:
    backend btrfs-progs-sudo
snapshot_preserve_min 7d
stream_compress no
volume /
 snapshot_dir .snapshots
 subvolume @home

but it says that it is meant to be read-only.
I think this is because I have it defined in my NixOS config file, as follows:
 #BTRFS automatic snapshots of Home
  services.btrbk.instances."btrbk" = {
    onCalendar = "*:0";
    settings = {
      snapshot_preserve_min = "7d";
      volume."/" = {
        subvolume = "@home";
        snapshot_dir = ".snapshots";
       };
    };
  };

